# Using multiple databases for one application in grails

Tags: grails

How can we make web application use multiple databases in grails ? 
For Ex:  I have admin panel to register particular user and will assign him particular database while registering. when ever the particular user logs in to application he has to use the  database which i have assigned him while registering.
Note: I do not want to restart my application.

Comment: note: the moment you add a db, you'll need to restart. but as soon as you've configured your app to use two db's, why wouldn't that work?

Comment: How would you configure two databases? without restarting.

Comment: Have a look at the multi-tenant feature of the latest GORM versions (part of Grails). Here is a guide they wrote explaining how to use the feature : http://guides.grails.org/database-per-tenant/guide/index.html

Comment: Look into the direction of Multitenancy support in grails 3 along with a custom tenant resolver based on the logged in user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bassmartin and @Sudhir N suggest in your scenario multi-tenancy is the way to go, http://guides.grails.org/database-per-tenant/guide/index.html is an excellent starting point you can check the [gorm for hibernate](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html) documentation to get more information about tenancy and multiple data sources

At the time there are a couple more guides about multiple-tenancy in [grails guide site](http://guides.grails.org/#/index)

Just remember you will need to use at least GORM 6.0 to use tenancy

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through this to use multiple datasource

> http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources